# Jquery Tree view, nestable, sortable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui

I am working on a codeIgniter project regarding an organisation, I have a section where i need to show the Organisation structure in the Following Format : [image: Image Format]

The items in the image represent a department each.

The user should be able to sort, add and delete the departments. I have tried few plugins but they do not allow nesting beyond a level.

I would be thankful if somebody could suggest me a good plugin or some solution to implement this.

Comment: why a plugin? do it yourself.

Comment: i can do that myself also, but it will take some time, looking for a quick solution.